# Class Attributes not updating in program

Tags: python

I am fairly new to coding on Python. In my code, I am trying to change the myPlayer.hp and myPlayer.sp values based on what the myPlayer.job is. But, for some reason, regardless of job, the HP and SP values are still 0 when I check them in the program. If you know how to change them, please let me know and thank you.
Here is the code that deals with my question:

```
class player:
  def __init__(self):
    self.name = ''
    self.job = ''
    self.hp = 0
    self.sp = 0
    self.pwr = 0
    self.res = 0
    self.agi = 0
    self.smr = 0
    self.wll = 0
    self.status_effects = []
    self.location = 'b2'
    self.game_over = False
myPlayer = player()

def main_game_loop():
  while myPlayer.game_over is False:
    prompt()


def setup_game():
  os.system('cls')

question1 = "Hello, what's your name?\n"
for character in question1:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
player_name = input("> ")
myPlayer.name = player_name

question2 = "Hello, what role do you want to play?\n"
question2added = "(You can play as a warrior, mage, or priest)\n"
for character in question2:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.05)
for character in question2added:
    sys.stdout.write(character)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(0.01)
player_job = input("> ")
valid_jobs = ['warrior', 'mage', 'priest']
if player_job.lower() in valid_jobs:
    myPlayer.job = player_job
    print("You are now a " + player_job + "!\n")
while player_job.lower() not in valid_jobs:
    player_job = input("> ")
    if player_job.lower() in valid_jobs:
        myPlayer.job = player_job
        print("You are now a " + player_job + "!\n")
if myPlayer.job == 'warrior':
    myPlayer.hp = 25
    myPlayer.sp = 0
elif myPlayer.job == 'mage':
    myPlayer.hp = 15
    myPlayer.sp = 20
elif myPlayer.job == 'priest':
    myPlayer.hp = 20
    myPlayer.sp = 15
```

Comment: Please repeat the intro tour, starting with [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [MRE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).  Give us a descriptive title and **minimal** code that **exhibits** the problem.  Your posted code hangs waiting for input and includes a lot of irrelavant code.

Comment: Why the down votes? I see code, I see a description of the problem.

Comment: I had to add a couple of imports and prints for the variables at the end, but the code worked fine. .sp and .hp got their assignments. So far there is no bug.

Comment: @tdelaney: Same for me. Maybe some error with the indentation in the QA's local version...

Answer (score 0):

Your code isn't necessarily incorrect, but there is a good chance for an error when the player enters their job.

You have the following code:

```
if player_job.lower() in valid_jobs:
```

That means that if the player enters `Warrior` you understand that they meant `warrior`. That is good. But when you assign the player's job you do the following:

```
myPlayer.job = player_job
```

That can cause a problem, since you aren't calling `lower()` on the job.

Instead, you likely want:

```
myPlayer.job = player_job.lower()
```

That way, when you look at the player's job to assign `sp` and `hp` it will match the lowercase strings you are comparing it to.